New @Observable Macro: Should private properties be @ObservationIgnored? (iOS 17+)
All articles I read put @ObservationIgnored for private properties. However, Apple in their Focus Cookbook sample project, didn't put @ObservationIgnored to private properties.

What “all articles” did you read? Please add some links.

It depends, do you want something  to happen if they change? You can use observation tracking to trigger a “didSet” type behavior. Ignore them when they can’t be observed or when you don’t need to do anything if they change. Private properties can be set to ignored but they don’t have to, it all depends on if you need “didSet”.

Apple's documentation [1] says

Observation doesn’t require a property wrapper to make a property observable. Instead, the accessibility of the property in relationship to an observer, such as a view, determines whether a property is observable.


If you have properties that are accessible to an observer that you don’t want to track, apply the ObservationIgnored() macro to the property.

[1] https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

my two cents...
I think a decent explanation is on ADC site:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/763664
I found interesting the effect of "private".
Useful for others:

"@Observable" macro cannot be prepended to computed vars:
You got:
'extension' macro cannot be attached to property ('....')

seems to me weird.. but is allowed to prepend "@ObservationIgnored " to computed property without warnings / errors. (maybe wanted..)


